# Can Hibernate Search index build performance be improved using projection?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have an entity containing around 40 columns and 7 collections. The collections are not lazy loaded. Indexing 500 000 entities using Hibernate Search MassIndexer takes around 2-3 hours. I use the code below:

```
fullTextSession.createIndexer()
        .batchSizeToLoadObjects(1000)
        .threadsToLoadObjects(8).start();
```

I even tried using lazy loading to see what the difference would be, and then it takes around 1 hour, which is not as fast as I would hope for.

To try out what the performance would be like if having an entity containing only the columns that I want to index, 3 columns including the ID column, I created an entity containing only those three columns. Indexing was now very rapid, it only took 3 minutes.

The approach to use a different entity is not what I want since it would require a manual update of the index every time the original entity is updated (as far as I understand how it works). I then thought of using the flushToIndexes() approach and projection, instead of MassIndexer.

I wrote up the code below based on https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-flushtoindexes and added the projection part.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
try {
    int batchSize = 1000;
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    fullTextSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
    fullTextSession.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
    Transaction transaction = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
    //Scrollable results will avoid loading too many objects in memory
    ScrollableResults results = fullTextSession.createCriteria( Report.class )
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("reportId"), "reportId")
                .add(Projections.property("header"), "header")
                .add(Projections.property("description"), "description")
                )
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Report.class))
        .setFetchSize(batchSize)
        .scroll( ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY );
    int index = 0;
    while( results.next() ) {
        index++;
        fullTextSession.index( results.get(0) ); //index each element
        if (index % batchSize == 0) {
            fullTextSession.flushToIndexes(); //apply changes to indexes
            fullTextSession.clear(); //free memory since the queue is processed
        }
    }
    transaction.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e);
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

When running the code I get an exception in the code (at `fullTextSession.index(results.get(0));`) when it tries to index the first element:

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The instance was not associated with this session

I don't understand why I get this exception. I have read that it can occur if using different Hibernate sessions, but in this case I am doing all work within one Hibernate session.

Have anyone else tried to use projection together with Hibernate Search indexing? Should it be possible to use? Any information on the subject is appreciated.

Some version information: I'm using Hibernate 4.2.17.Final and Hibernate Search 4.4.6.Final. I can't use the latest version because of dependencies.

Comment: I became a little bit suspicious regarding the difference between using lazy loading and not using it. I run the tests once more and now I got around 1 hour for both. I guess the previous difference could be because of temporary database performance issues or something like that. In my case it seems like it does fetch eagerly despite what value I set for `@LazyCollection`. I will see if I can get any clue why I see this behaviour.

Comment: The reason why lazy loading did not work, was because of extra functionality in the setter method for the collections which populated a Map with data from the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using projections is (currently) not an option as a projected result is not associated with the object: it's transient.
The *FullTextSession#index()* method is expecting a managed object, so you get the *TransientObjectException*.

Back when designing the *MassIndexer* I considered using projections but it didn't seem to get me a significant benefit; it's interesting that you report this being useful in your case. Are you sure that all your relations are lazy and also are you sure that the indexing process isn't going to need those lazily loaded relations?

If you could confirm that you see such a significant performance benefit just by loading some less columns of data, we could look into patching that. Ideally we could make this optimisation transparent to the user, to not need adding more configuration options.

In my experience though the primary slowdown is due to the multiple roundtrips needed to the database to load all the relations; usually you can get a great performance boost by making sure all relations are lazy, and enabling 2nd level caching for the relations you need to load during indexing.. depending on your model, caching could be more effective than projections.

But I realize I'm making some assumptions on how the entities are modelled, so your report is very interesting. Please open a new "Improvement" JIRA [on our issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH).

Comment: First, thanks for your answer regarding the possibility to use projections.

Comment: Enter was posting my comment I realized. Here comes the rest of the comment:

I have marked all collections `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)`. I can't see why the indexing process should need those lazily loaded relations.

Based on your input I made a test where I set `@Transient` for all collections. Then the index build takes only 3 minutes.

Any clue why this could be?

Comment: Is the loaded collection marked @IndexedEmbedded, or is there anything else (like a ClassBridge on your main entity) possibly loading the collection? Or maybe a faulty "toString()" implementation? Would love it if you could breackpoint and find out why, if Search loads it for no reason we should definitely fix it!

Comment: Neither `@IndexedEmbedded` nor `@ClassBridge` annotations are present. The `toString()` implementation is just returning class name and report ID. When breakpointing I see that the set methods are called, but I can't see any calls to the get methods. Seems like lazy loading is ignored. I don't know why really. Should anything more be needed than marking as `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)`?

Comment: Regardless of whether I get lazy loading to work or not, I will in my case need to continue to use eager loading (since I must keep the original application behaviour), and it would therefore be a benefit if only the columns and collections needed for indexing were loaded. I created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1813 regarding this matter.

Comment: Now I know why lazy loading did not work. See the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500459/can-hibernate-search-index-build-performance-be-improved-using-projection#comment45550418_28500459) above, below the question.